# process.env.VAR missing on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, environment-variables

I have variable that I am attempting to reference via access via process.env.VAR_NAME. It was working fine when I was developing on my local machine (a Mac), but doesn't seem to work on the Ubuntu server I deployed to. The server has the variable in /etc/environment, which I believed was the correct file for settings, but it's undefined when I run the app. I have also tried calling export VAR_NAME=... before starting the node server, but that also didn't seem to help.

Comment: Have you tried something like: `VAR_NAME=something node .` (all one line)? If you are not launching node like `node .`, how are you executing it?

Comment: Ah, so I tried that, and accidentally didn't include sudo and it worked. However, when I run sudo node ... I lose the variables. Is that standard behavior with sudo?

Comment: Actually, if I `sudo VAR=... node .` then it works. Is there a better way to do that? I would prefer not to pass in the variable on launch each time.